# Converter works for RequestParameter but not for RequestBody field

Tags: spring-boot, converters

I have the following converter:

```
@Component
public class CountryEnumConverter implements Converter<String, CountryEnum> {

    @Override
    public CountryEnum convert(String country) {
        CountryEnum countryEnum = CountryEnum.getBySign(country);

        if (countryEnum == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(country + " - Country is not supported!");
        }

        return countryEnum;
    }
}
```

Registered it is invoked when used for RequestParam

```
@GetMapping(value = RestApiEndpoints.RESULTS, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResultDto> getResults(
        Principal principal,
        @RequestParam CountryEnum country) {
    ....
}
```

But this converter is never invoked when used for field in the RequstBody:

```
@GetMapping(value = RestApiEndpoints.RESULTS, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResultDto> getResults(
        Principal principal,
        @RequestBody MyBody myBody) {
    ....
}
```

---

```
public class MyBody {

    @NotNull
    private CountryEnum country;


    public MyBody() {
    }

    public CountryEnum getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(CountryEnum country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if I add the following code to my `CountryEnum` will do the trick.

```
@JsonCreator
public static CountryEnum fromString(String value) {
    CountryEnumConverter converter = new CountryEnumConverter();
    return converter.convert(value);
}
```

Comment: But doesn't answer your question which is why the existing converter wasn't invoked! It is also a limited solution as 1. A model class is now directly invoking infrastucure code and 2. more complex conversions (perhaps via db lookups) cannot be done as the new Converter instance is no longer a Spring managed bean.

Answer (score 2):

Your existing `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` instance will only work with data submitted as form encoded data. With `@RequestBody` you are sending JSON data which will be deserialized using using the Jackson library.

You can then create an instance of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdConverter<IN, OUT>`

```
public class StringToCountryTypeConverter extends StdConverter<String, CountryType> {

  @Override
  public CountryType convert(String value) {
      //convert and return
  }
}
```

and then apply this on the target property:

```
public class MyBody {

    @NotNull
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToCountryTypeConverter.class)
    private CountryEnum country;
}
```

Given the similarity of the 2 interfaces I would expect that you could create one class to handle both scenarios:

```
public class StringToCountryTypeConverter extends StdConverter<String, CountryType> 
           implements org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<String, CountryType> {
  @Override
  public CountryType convert(String value) {
      //convert and return
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw this, but I am using `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` and this expects `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.Converter`

Comment: As I noted in my answer: *Your existing Converter [org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter] will **only** handle data submitted as form encoded data.*. So therefore it is of no use when working with Json Data

Comment: See my update. If required, you can probably have one class to handle both scenarios.